# what optimization passes are done for -O4 in clang?

Tags: llvm, clang, llvm-clang

We are trying to implement a jit compiler whose performance is supposed to be same as doing it with clang -o4. Is there a place where I could easily get the list of optimization passes invoked by clang with -o4 is specified?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know -O4 means same thing as -O3 + enabled LTO (Link Time Optimization).
See the folloing code fragments:

- [Tools.cpp](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/Driver/Tools.cpp#L2291) `// Manually translate -O to -O2 and -O4 to -O3;`
- [Driver.cpp](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/Driver/Driver.cpp#L1175) `// Check for -O4.`

Also see [here](http://llvm.org/docs/GoldPlugin.html):

> You can produce bitcode files from clang using -emit-llvm or -flto, or the -O4 flag which is synonymous with -O3 -flto.

For optimizations used with -O3 flag see this [PassManagerBuilder.cpp](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/lib/Transforms/IPO/PassManagerBuilder.cpp#L118) file (look for OptLevel variable - it will have value 3).

Comment: Note: This is no longer correct. The manual now explicitly states that "                -O4 and higher:  Currently equivalent to -O3". People who are using O4 and think they're doing LTO, aren't.

Answer (score 9):

Note that as of LLVM version 5.1 -O4 no longer implies link time optimization. If you want that you need to pass -flto. See [Xcode 5 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/xc5_release_notes/xc5_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH2-SW12).

Comment: Please use LLVM versions when talking about LLVM, not Apple LLVM versions - LLVM is currently at 3.5, so 5.1 is non-existent.