# std::unique_ptr memory and performance

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, unique-ptr

> When you reach for a smart pointer, std::unique_ptr should generally
>   be the one closest at hand. It’s reasonable to assume that, by
>   default, **std::unique_ptrs are the same size as raw pointers, and for
>   most operations (including dereferencing), they execute exactly the
>   same instructions. This means you can use them even in situations
>   where memory and cycles are tight.** If a raw pointer is small enough
>   and fast enough for you, a std::unique_ptr almost certainly is, too.

-Scott Meyers (Effective Modern C++)

How the bold part can be true, it takes two phases to find the raw ptr in smart ptr and then call the method. How they can be equally fast?

Comment: What is "find the raw ptr in smart ptr" ? The actual pointer is (usually) just a member of a smart pointer, there is no need to "find" anything.

Comment: Optimizations. It's the wonderful part about C++ that everyone can enjoy!

Comment: The indirection is most likely optimized out because all the code is available to the optimizer.

Comment: It's Scott M**e**yers by the way.

Comment: @ʎǝɹɟɟɟǝſ don't you know Mayers? Leading export on preformance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much is the overhead of smart pointers compared to normal pointers in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22295665/1938163)

Comment: @ʎǝɹɟɟɟǝſ Scott has given some very valuable input for us working in the embedded field. Less valuable for the krethi and plethi working on a PC. There they shouldn't think about any premature optimizations in 1st place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There likely is no "raw ptr in smart ptr". The smart pointer will just be the raw pointer. There is nothing you need that indirection would give you.

Comment: when you call `smartPtr->doF()` you get `smartPtr->rawPtr->doF()` right?

Comment: @Narek No. You just get `rawPtr->doF()`. What does the indirection do that can't be eliminated? It's no different from `int a = 3; return a;`. The compiler will just generate the same code as it would if you did `return 3;`.

Comment: You mean compiler easily optimizes away?

Comment: @Narek Yes. The compiler doesn't have to put code to look up something it can determine at compile time. The compiler knows at compile time where the raw pointer is, so why should it look at the smart pointer to get it? And then once it never needs the smart pointer for anything, it just removes it.

Comment: In fact it is  "smartPtr.rawPtr->doF()" and this means the offset (which is always 0) can be calculated and used. There is not even optimization involved as this is the normal function invocation and you get it with -O0.