# How do I check if a pointer as a data member in a class in C++ has been initialized?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-arrays, dynamic-allocation

I have a data member in a class which is a pointer. Also, I have a setter function to dynamically allocate this pointer, let's say, for the purpose of a dynamic array. Before setting new values, I need to delete this pointer to avoid memory leak. I wonder how do I check if this pointer is initialized so that if it is not initialized, I don't need to delete the pointer's memory before setting new values.

Comment: set to `nullptr` when it's not in use or do the sane thing and just use a `unique_ptr` to handle the lifetimes for you. Incidentally, calling `delete` on `nullptr` does nothing, anyway.

Comment: Do you mean setting default values for the member as `nullptr`? I wonder how this is done in C++?@jaggedSpire

Comment: yep. just set it to `nullptr` with in class member initialization, in the member initializer list, or in the constructor body

Comment: If you use the `unique_ptr` be sure to use the `T[]` variant that's declared like `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`, where `T` is the type you're dynamically allocating arrays of. It calls `delete[]` on its internal pointer as you're supposed to with arrays.

Comment: @jaggedSpire `std::unique_ptr` sounds great, but just wonder if there's any performance cost (meaning slow down the speed) for using this magic `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: not really. Unique_ptr is designed for minimal overhead over a raw pointer with manual memory management.

Answer (score 4):

You have two options. First, you can do everything by hand and set it to `nullptr` in the constructor. Then before allocating new memory you can check if it's `nullptr` and delete it if it's not. What I would recommend instead is using a smart pointer, like `std::unique_ptr`. You can call `reset` on it every time you need to set it to a new pointer and never worry about memory leaks. It will make sure to delete previously allocated memory, if any.

Comment: In your first scenario, you don't need to check for NULL before deleting it. `delete` handles null pointers properly.

Comment: @PeteBecker 1. You mean I still need to set it to `nullptr` but don't need to check its nullity before `delete`? 2. My pointer might be a dynamic array in the future, then does `delete [] a_pointer;` also work properly on `nullptr`?

Comment: @grigor `std::unique_ptr` sounds great, but just wonder if there's any performance cost (meaning slow down the speed) for using this magic `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: Short answer is not really. Longer answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295665/how-much-is-the-overhead-of-smart-pointers-compared-to-normal-pointers-in-c

Comment: @PeteBecker I know that if the pointer in class is not initialized to `nullptr`, it gets a junk value. Then does `delete` even handle this junk value well? Reading your comment, I am thinking now do I really need to initialize the pointer.