Smart pointer produces inefficient compiled code
I'm implementing a BST and believe it’s a good idea to use unique_ptr to represent child node ownership. However, I discovered that smart pointers cause the compiler to prefer branching over branchless code (specifically cmov). I’m using g++-13 to compile on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. I tried using the ternary operator to encourage branchless code, but it hasn’t worked. Here’s a simple prototype
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
struct node {
    int val;
    node* left_child;
    node* right_child;
};

struct smart_node {
    int val;
    std::unique_ptr<smart_node> left_child;
    std::unique_ptr<smart_node> right_child;
};

node*
__attribute__((noinline))
raw(node* root, int key) {
    node* prev = root;
    node* curr = prev -> left_child;
    while (curr != nullptr) {
        prev = curr;
        bool comp = key < (curr -> val);
        curr = comp ? curr -> left_child : curr -> right_child;
    }
    return prev;
}

smart_node*
__attribute__((noinline))
smart(std::unique_ptr<smart_node> root, int key) {
    smart_node* prev = root.get();
    smart_node* curr = prev -> left_child.get();
    while (curr != nullptr) {
        prev = curr;
        bool comp = key < (curr -> val);
        curr = comp ? curr -> left_child.get() : curr -> right_child.get();
    }
    return prev;
}

int main() {
    // Use null instead of a non-degenerative tree to shorten the code
    // I verified this doesn't cause the assembly of the two functions above to mutate
    auto last1 = raw(nullptr, 1);
    auto last2 = smart(std::make_unique<smart_node>(), 1);
    std::cout << last1 -> val << last2 -> val;
}


Below is the assembly code for the loop in raw.
    1310:   48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
    1313:   48 8b 42 10             mov    0x10(%rdx),%rax
    1317:   3b 32                   cmp    (%rdx),%esi
    1319:   48 0f 4c 42 08          cmovl  0x8(%rdx),%rax
    131e:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
    1321:   75 ed                   jne    1310 <_Z3rawP4nodei+0x20>

Below is the assembly code for the loop in smart.
    1360:   48 8b 50 08             mov    0x8(%rax),%rdx
    1364:   48 85 d2                test   %rdx,%rdx
    1367:   74 10                   je     1379 <_Z5smartSt10unique_ptrI10smart_nodeSt14default_deleteIS0_EEi+0x39>
    1369:   48 89 d0                mov    %rdx,%rax
    136c:   3b 30                   cmp    (%rax),%esi
    136e:   7c f0                   jl     1360 <_Z5smartSt10unique_ptrI10smart_nodeSt14default_deleteIS0_EEi+0x20>
    1370:   48 8b 50 10             mov    0x10(%rax),%rdx
    1374:   48 85 d2                test   %rdx,%rdx
    1377:   75 f0                   jne    1369 <_Z5smartSt10unique_ptrI10smart_nodeSt14default_deleteIS0_EEi+0x29>

In benchmark (2e6 call to a tree with 2e6 nodes), the branching code takes about 1.4x time the branchless version. I used RelWithDebInfo so O2 optimization is on. My question is how I can force compiler to use cmov? I read this post and it seems that there is no clean way to force this behavior. If it is not possible, I'd like to know why the compiler generates different code for the two cases.
To clarify, I don't want assembly since it is not portable. I used assembly to force the branchless version, but it is not the direction I want to pursue.

There is a guideline not to use naked new/delete. However since you are writing a datastructure (with unit tests) just use new/delete. Since you will promise the user of your tree class all memory managment is done for them.

I habitually use -O3 for performance testing (and release), so trying once with only -O2 seems bizarre to me. Did you not try any other options?

@PepijnKramer could you clarify? The code above is just a prototype to reproduce the issue. The real code is too big to show here.

What I mean is you shoulld create a BST tree class, hide the node managment inside it. And then you don't have to use unique_ptr's and can use more efficient code inside the tree class. Good software development focuses on easy to use correctly (e.g. let the BST class manage all the memory). It doesn't mean the implementation should be "the easiest" specially not if you're going to optimize

@Useless O3 produced the same assembly code. I used O2 because people seem to recommend to stick to RelWithDebInfo (which uses O2).

@PepijnKramer I appreciate your response, but this is just a prototype for people to reproduce the issue. This question is about branching vs branchless.

Ah ok I missed that point sorry, since the title refers to smartpointers. And smart pointers can introduce branching, so that's why I refered to using raw pointers.

@PepijnKramer I know I could implement with raw pointers. In fact the reason I discovered this performance issue was from benchmarking my red black tree against gcc red black tree. I keep hearing people say "smart pointers don't add overhead for most cases", so I'd like to see if this statement is true.

Have you read this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295665/how-much-is-the-overhead-of-smart-pointers-compared-to-normal-pointers-in-c (smart pointers can have overhead)

I can even think of a pointerless implementation. one vector to store nodes (using placement new), one vector to store "deleted" nodes (in the vector's internal range, if none are present allocate at the end of the vector) so you can use gaps in the vector of node first. (use popback if not emtpy). Optimization usually is found by doing more than changing one pointer type for another.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Looks like a QoI issue. clang trunk produces exact same code for both versions.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Thanks! This at least confirms I'm not doing anything weird. I also implemented my own unique_ptr as a quick test. No dice. Something interesting is (comp ? curr -> left_child : curr -> right_child).get() produces cmov but it first lea the left/right child address before the cmov and a mov %(rax) %rax, so still not great.

The program has undefined behavior since you dereference nullptr.

@TedLyngmo Thanks. I'm aware of that. This is just a prototype so people can generate the assembly code to tinker around. I marked no inline so raw and smart aren't affected by the nullptr

@cppishard I'm not saying it will fix it, but the assembly from a program with undefined behavior could look like just about anything.

@TedLyngmo true. I first made a prototype without this problem and I replaced the full tree generation code with a nullptr to shrink the code size. I verified the asm code looks the same (due to no inline most likely). Looks like it just causes more distraction to people.

It's odd to take the unique_ptr<smart_node> by value, and it is a significant difference from the raw version. Consider making the smart version take a smart_node*. The function doesn't care about ownership, and it might help get similar asssembly.

@FrançoisAndrieux this is a minimal code example to reproduce the issue. The real code is simpler with unique ptr. It’s certainly possible to implement with raw pointers, but I don’t want to go there so soon.

std::set and std::map are already defined as threaded red-black trees, so you won't need to reinvent them. But in case you ever need to implement your own data structures, std::unique_ptr is generally the wrong pick. Ownership of all nodes belongs to the tree, not the parrent node. Simplistic implementations using smart pointers may cause random stack overflow upon destruction.

@cppishard You can still make the function work with smart pointers, and use a raw pointer or reference to smart_node as the function parameter type. I would argue that having the argument be a smart pointer or reference to smart pointer is a probably a design error in the first place.

__attribute__((noinline)) in GCC isn't sufficient to fully hide one function body from a caller.  Use __attribute__((noipa)) to fully block all InterProcedural Analysis, fully opaque like it was non-inline and only defined in another compilation unit.  Use __attribute__((noipa,noinline)) so it works with Clang, too, which doesn't support noipa.  (@TedLyngmo)

I'm not surprised that the asm in the caller is the same in this case, but it's something you should at least [edit] the question to say you've checked.  Because it is something that needs to be verified.  Oh wait, these are functions being called on args with null pointers, not calling functions that deref null.  The non-inlined definitions have to work for any args which don't lead to UB.  So that's fine.  In GCC, if it made a special version for the null args, it would name it smart.constprop_1234 or something in the asm.

@Red.Wave "Ownership of all nodes belongs to the tree." This is an interesting take. The practical motivation behind my use is 1) to prohibit a node becoming the child of two different parents and 2) not having to set empty children to null. Semantically why isn't "left/right child" the property of parent? I agree this concept dissolves when I have to rotate nodes.

@PeterCordes the noipa trick is new to me. Thanks. I added an inline comment to explain why nullptr is used.

@PeterCordes Was that comment about __attribute__s really meant for me? If so, I don't get to what I wrote it was a comment :-)

@TedLyngmo: you were pointing out UB in the whole program as a reason not to trust the asm generated.  I was pointing out that noipa will ensure that code-gen for one function isn't influenced by visible UB in its callers (since it won't inline) or its callees (if you use noipa on those callees so the caller treats them as a total black box).  Even without that, the asm generated for a non-inline version of the function (as long as it isn't a .constprop clone) has to be correct for any args that don't lead to UB, so the existence of one call-site with nullptr isn't a problem w/o inlining

@PeterCordes Aha, I get it. Thanks for clarifying.

Reordering the nodes and possibly self-balancing is the responsibility of the tree. If you leave the ownership to members, at the very least the destruction becomes hazardous. Example: create a completely degenerated tree(essentially a singly linked list) with 10M elements; on an average machine that could trigger a stack overflow, because of recursive destruction with a depth of 10M.

@Red.Wave I'm not using it for destruction even since it causes unique ptr to have to carry a reference to the container allocator and bloat the unique ptr. Stack overflow isn't a problem since the tree is balanced, so it isn't very deep. I mainly use it to facilitate correctness.

In order to keep it balanced, the control must be left to the tree and not the nodes. That means the owner is essentially the tree, not the parent node. The container allocator is generally supposed to be an empty type, thus creating a deleter out of it doesn't create any overhead. But if the allocator is not in anyway referenced by the smart pointer, that just shows a serious flaw in design: There will be memory leaks.

g++ 13 indeed produces worse code for the smart pointers. Newer versions of gcc (14.2) seem to produce almost identical code, though.
You can get even better assembly by eliminating even the inlined branch entirely while still holding the branches in unique pointers.
struct sv_node {
    int val;
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<sv_node>,2> child{};
};

sv_node*
__attribute__((noinline))
svec(sv_node* root, int key) {
    auto prev = root;
    auto curr = prev->child[0].get();
    while (curr != nullptr) {
        prev = curr;
        bool const comp = key >= (curr->val);
        curr = curr->child[comp].get();
    }
    return prev;
}

This produces the following assembly with gcc 13.3:
svec(sv_node*, int):
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        test    rdx, rdx
        je      .L19
.L21:
        xor     eax, eax
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rdx], esi
        mov     rdi, rdx
        setle   al
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdx+8+rax*8]
        test    rdx, rdx
        jne     .L21
.L19:
        mov     rax, rdi
        ret

(live demo)
You can also, instead of using std::array<std::unique_ptr<node>,2>, make it an std::vector<node> with similar assembly but slightly different traversal logic. And I suspect similar performance.
However, very importantly, in order to figure out performance, you have to benchmark. Just looking at assembly will not be sufficient.

For a BST that doesn't fit in (L1d or L2) cache, branchy asm lets branch-prediction + speculative exec work as data prefetch, which despite the cost of branch mispredicts is typically faster than asm like this with a data dependency.

Also, not sure xor-zero / setcc / mov using it in the addressing mode is better than loading both and letting cmp/cmov pick which load result to use.  cmov reg,mem unconditionally loads its memory source operand, overlapping that latency with the compare.  But setcc puts an extra load-use latency on the critical path: after a node pointer is ready, load the key and compare, and only then start loading the correct pointer.

Yup, https://uica.uops.info/ predicts this setcc loop runs 11c / iter on Skylake, dependency bottleneck.  The OP's CMOV loop at 7c / iter.  Skylake's load-use latency is 4 cycles when a load is used directly as an input to another load (and the offset doesn't cross a 4K boundary, since it optimistically shortcuts adding the displacement before checking the TLB.)

These are extremely fair points, I agree.
